# JobTrackingWithFinalizers feature-gate on GKE autopilot cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, argo-workflows

I have a GKE autopilot cluster running on `1.24.0-gke.1000`, from the rapid release channel. The Kubernetes documentation states that the feature-gate `JobTrackingWithFinalizers` has reached beta status from version 1.23 onwards.
Beta features should be enabled by default, but Google can choose to disable certain Beta features. However, afaik there is no documentation that lists the excluded features.

When I run `kubectl cluster-info dump | grep feature-gate` I get the following output:

```
"kube-proxy --cluster-cidr=10.44.128.0/17 --oom-score-adj=-998 --v=2 --feature-gates=DynamicKubeletConfig=false,InTreePluginAWSUnregister=true,InTreePluginAzureDiskUnregister=true,InTreePluginOpenStackUnregister=true,InTreePluginvSphereUnregister=true,NetworkPolicyEndPort=false,CSIMigrationGCE=true --iptables-sync-period=1m --iptables-min-sync-period=10s --ipvs-sync-period=1m --ipvs-min-sync-period=10s --detect-local-mode=NodeCIDR 1\u003e\u003e/var/log/kube-proxy.log 2\u003e\u00261"
```

So it seems like the feature is NOT disabled, but still it doesn't work. Jobs with Indexed Completion Mode are tracked without the Finalizer.
I need this feature, because I am using Indexed Jobs with Spot-VMs. This results in the Succeeded Pods getting deleted when a Node is evicted, which reschedules them, even though they already succeeded.
My current solution is to use Argo Workflows, which features a separate workflow-controller deployment. But with the `JobTrackingWithFinalizers` feature, I could achieve what I need without Argo Workflows.

Is there any way to find out if/when this feature will be available on GKE?
Or has anyone found another solution that solves this issue in a smart way?

Answer (score 0):

This [feature gate is available but turned off by default in Kubernetes 1.24](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/), you will need to upgrade to 1.25 to use this feature.

Status  Type.   From.   Till
false   Alpha   1.22    1.22
false   Beta    1.23    1.24
true    Beta    1.25    1.25
true    GA      1.26